# Find volume of solid using shell method

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2$, $y=0$, $x=1$, and $x=2$ about the line $x=4$.

Here is what I attempted with the shell method, but it is clearly wrong:
[image: Attempt]

Answer (score 3):

If we are rotating about the $y$-axis ($x=0$), then the formula is

$$2\pi\int_a^b xf(x) \, dx.$$

For your problem, rather than $x=0$, the rotation is about $x=4$.

The integral of interest should be

$$2\pi \int_1^2 (4-x)x^2\, dx.$$

Alternatively, to some, it might be easier to view it as rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=(x-8)^2, y=0, x=6,$ and $x=7$ about the line $x=4$. This can be observed by a reflection.

which is equivalent to rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=(x-4)^2, y=0, x=2,$ and $x=3$ about the line $x=0$. This can be observed by a translation.

That is you can also just evaluate $$2\pi \int_2^3x(x-4)^2 \, dx.$$